# Hiding Columns in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 worksheets in 1 excel workbook. I am attempting to store Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet4 in an array. Then, I am wanting the program to hide all columns in the array that do not have the value "FY" in row 8. The purpose of this is to be able to view the FY rows with ease and to leave Sheet3 from hiding any columns.

Here is a screenshot of the excel file:
[image]

and here is my code snippet:

```
Sub FY_HIDE222()    
    Dim keyCells As Range
    Dim ws As Variant
    ws = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4")

    For Each sh In ws
        For Each keyCells In ws.Range("C8:ZZ8").Cells
            If keyCells.Value <> "FY" Then
                keyCells.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next keyCells
    Next sh
End Sub
```

I am receiving a syntax error on this line:

```
For Each keyCells In ws.Range("C8:ZZ8").Cells
```

saying "keyCells = nothing"...Please assist in my thinking as I am thinking the keyCells variable should have FY, Q1, Q2, etc. stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `sh is fetching string value only not Worksheet object. Try

```
Sub FY_HIDE222()
Dim keyCells As Range
Dim wsName As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
wsName = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4")
    For Each sh In wsName
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh)
        For Each keyCells In ws.Range("C8:ZZ8").Cells
            If keyCells.Value <> "FY" Then
                keyCells.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next keyCells
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: wsName is an array not an object, so you can not use for each. You have to use LBound and UBound.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I agree in conventional coding that's the only way and may arise problem from `option base.`But why refrain from out of box thinking when the way it is used here by the author is working correct.   objective is to pin point source of the error.

Comment: @QHarr: You are absolutely right, I've tested it (couldn't believe it). Sorry for spreading misinformation.

Comment: Thank you both for the assistance. Ahmed, thank you for solving my initial error. VBasic, thank you for enlightening the Lbound/Ubound functionality to me. I went ahead and read a couple of articles on it, so much appreciated.

Comment: @Ahmed AU: My apologies for not recognizing that this was a working code. Since I always use Option Explicit the code failed on the first 'For Each' line and when I added 'Dim sh' it failed again on the second 'For Each' line, so I WRONGly assumed that the first 'For each' line was wrong (it had to be an 'LBound-UBound' approach, I thought). Since I use Excel 2003 there is no ZZ8, forgetting to change it to Z8 kept me from making it work.

Comment: Could anyone flag my first comment. I can't do it myself.

Comment: @VBasic2008 No question of flagging. I believe even expert of the experts make silly mistakes and learn from it. Without absurd misadventure into coding & silly mistakes our learning will come to a halt. lets look at example of this post, how may constructive and  enlightening approaches/solutions (including yours)  arises from a simple single _Overlook _. I am always against any down voting and flagging except in the case of rude abuse.

Answer (score 3):

To keep it as simple as possible

```
Dim wsName, i As Long, c As Range
wsName = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4")

    For i = LBound(wsName) To UBound(wsName)
        For Each c In Sheets(i).Range("C8:ZZ8")
            If c.Value <> "FY" Then c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Next c
    Next i
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning they could use Union so long as union object is set to nothing before next sheet.

Comment: @QHarr - Since I only consider myself an intermediate at best. I have used Union to combine ranges in a worksheet, but that is my limit of usage. I would find it very educational to see an answer to this question using the Union method.

Comment: Have done. In yours do you need Worksheets(wsName(i)) ? +1

Comment: @QHarr - Yes sir

Answer (score 2):

You can use union to gather qualifying ranges in the same sheet and hide in one go. If you want to go the extra mile you could re-write to loop the columns of the range and exit a loop of any given column at the first qualifying cell as you are hiding the entire column anyway.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim wsName, i As Long, c As Range, unionRng As Range
    wsName = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4")

    For i = LBound(wsName) To UBound(wsName)
        For Each c In Worksheets(wsName(i)).Range("C8:ZZ8")
            If c.Value <> "FY" Then
                If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, c)
                Else
                    Set unionRng = c
                End If
            End If
        Next c
        If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then 
            unionRng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Set unionRng = Nothing
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Recap, for each sheet you combine every column that has "FY" using `Union` and then hide all at the same time. Then you reset the `unionRng` back to nothing before the next sheet. Thanks, outstanding +1

Comment: Since the OP's image indicates that there are fewer cells containing "FY" you could hide the entire range (after 'For i = LBound(wsName) To UBound(wsName)') with 'Sheets(wsName(i)).Range("C8:Z8").EntireColumn.Hidden = True' and then change the lines 'If c.Value = "FY" Then' and 'If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireColumn.Hidden = False' to make it even more efficient (faster).

Comment: I would still have to loop the same number of columns though?

Comment: @QHarr: That's true, but I guess it takes less time to hide all columns and then to show the few containing "FY" than to hide the many columns not containing "FY". In my sample 4 out of 24 columns the code finished almost twice as fast  In a sample 4 out of 254 it was almost 20 times faster. Of course this is all hairsplitting since we're talking about milliseconds. My comment wasn't about criticizing your code but to indicate that there is another approach. BTW what's the extra mile all about?

Answer (score 1):

## Show Some, Show All

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub FY_HIDE222()

  Const cStrRange = "C8:ZZ8"
  Const cStrText = "FY"

  Dim objWs As Worksheet
  Dim objCell As Range
  Dim vntSheets As Variant
  Dim intCounter As Integer

  vntSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4")

  For intCounter = LBound(vntSheets) To UBound(vntSheets)

    Set objWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vntSheets(intCounter))

    For Each objCell In objWs.Range(cStrRange)

      If objCell.Value <> cStrText Then
        objCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      End If

    Next

  Next

End Sub
```

I have Excel 2003, so I used Z8 instead of ZZ8 which is obvious in the following picture.

[image]

```
Sub FY_SHOW222()

  Dim objWs As Worksheet
  Dim vntSheets As Variant
  Dim intCounter As Integer

  vntSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4")

  For intCounter = LBound(vntSheets) To UBound(vntSheets)

    Set objWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vntSheets(intCounter))

    objWs.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

  Next

End Sub
```

[image]